# Style React Native switch component

Tags: react-native, toggle, custom-component

I'm developing a mobile application using React Native. This project needs a custom button to provides a boolean type of input. But I have no idea how to create this kind of custom component for that. I did a research and I try to create this custom button with a react-native switch (import { Switch } from 'react-native';). But seems like It is difficult to style.

I'm not sure what would be the best way to achieve that? Using the switch component? Please help me to find a better solution or new approach for this.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a custom switch in react native and You can do the styling in it a source code is given below -

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: false
  }
  handleOFF = () => {
    this.setState({
      active: false
    });

  }

  handleOn = () => {
    this.setState({
      active: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MainView>
        <Label>
          <LabelOff onPress={this.handleOFF} active={this.state.active} activeOpacity={0.8}>
            <Off>OFF</Off>
          </LabelOff>
          <LabelOn onPress={this.handleOn} active={this.state.active} activeOpacity={0.8}>
            <On>ON</On>
          </LabelOn>
        </Label>
      </MainView>
    )
  }
}


const MainView = styled.View`
  margin:50px;
`
const Label = styled.View`
  height:60px;
  width:240px;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
  background-color:transparent;
`

const LabelOff = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  height:60px;
  width:120px;
  background-color:${props => props.active ? 'transparent' : '#cb6161'};
  border:2px solid #cb6161;
  border-right-width:0px;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-around;
`
const LabelOn = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  height:60px;
  width:120px;
  background-color:${props => props.active ? '#55acee' : 'transparent'};
  border:2px solid #55acee;
  border-left-width:0px;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-around;
`
const Off = styled.Text`
  font-size:22px;
`
const On = styled.Text`
  font-size:22px;
`
export default App
```

Custom switch is done !